# Finding only ethernet mac address using wmic

Tags: batch-file, ethernet, mac-address, wmic

I am using `Win32_NetworkAdapter` for finding only ethernet mac-addresses but for some reason it also report me WIFI as `802.3` in my laptop/pc.

Can you tell me what should I do for finding only ethernet mac addresses.
I want to find multiple ethernet mac addreses using batch file

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setx /M PATH "%%PATH%%;C:\Windows\System32\wbem"
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "PNPDeviceID like '%%PCI%%' AND NetConnectionStatus=2 AND AdapterTypeID='0'" get name, MacAddress,AdapterType
pause
```

Comment: Are you forced to use `wmic`? Can be done with `ipconfig /all`!

Comment: @double-beep yes to I have do with wmic but ipconfig/all gives all mac address. I want only ethernet mac address

Comment: We can select the one which fits you! BTW, do you have 2 ethernet mac addresses?

Comment: @double-beep Yes, I have 2 ethernet mac address and I wanted to get both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well an easy way to extract only the MAC address will to use a `FOR` loop.

```
@ECHO OFF

Rem | Get only the MAC Address
for /f "tokens=3 skip=1" %%a in ('wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "PNPDeviceID like '%%%%PCI%%%%' AND NetConnectionStatus=2 AND AdapterTypeID='0'" get name^,MacAddress^,AdapterType') do (Set "MacAddress=%%a")

Echo %MacAddress%
```

---

**EDIT:**

Being that your original script seems to only output one MAC address. Being that you need all `Ethernet` related MAC addresses we can use `IPCONFIG /ALL` to get the returning `Physical Address` or MAC Address.

Being that we need to extract only certain data from the mess `IPCOFIG` is, we will need to have a few extra FOR loops in the code block to extract data.

The script bellow will find all the adapters with the name "Ethernet" then proceed to set the `Physical Address` to a string. I put `REM`'s inside the script further explaining what each step of the code is doing. If you have any questions leave them bellow.

**Find MAC Addresses for Ethernet.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Expand ipconfig To Loop
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ipconfig /all') do (

    Rem | Only Find The Adapter Names With "Ethernet"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('Echo %%A^| find /V "."^| find /V "::"^| find /I ":"^| find /I "Ethernet"') do (

        Rem | Remove ":" From Output
        set "adapter=%%B"
        set adapter=!adapter::=%!

        Rem | Find the first "adapter" In ipconfig
        set adapterfound=false
        for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%f in ('ipconfig /all') do (
            set "item=%%f"
            if /i "!item!"=="!adapter!" (
                set adapterfound=true
            ) else if not "!item!"=="!item:Physical Address=!" if "!adapterfound!"=="true" (

                Rem | It Was Found, Extract Physical Address Data
                set "adress=%%g"
                set adress=!adress:* =%!
                set adapterfound=false
            )
        )

        Rem | Echo Each Result
        echo !adapter!: !adress!

    )
)

pause
GOTO :EOF
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.

Comment: Can it get only ethernet multiple mac address?becoz I have Ethernet1 and Ethernet2 mac adresses

Comment: @SharanaiyyaSwami Yes I will provide a better alternative to `wmic`.

Comment: @SharanaiyyaSwami Alright post was updated have a look.

Comment: Thanks John,You solved my problem I want to ask can I print mac addresses without : e.g E7E6E4E2E8E9

Comment: @SharanaiyyaSwami Yes you can with syntax-replacement. Use `set adress=!adress:-=%!`. This will remove the `-` From the MAC address.

Comment: @SharanaiyyaSwami Put the `set adress=!adress:-=%!` Under the `set adress=!adress:* =%!` Within the script.

Comment: I done John but I want to copy both address from clipboard.It works when one mac address is their but it failed when two is their.For that I used **echo %adress:-=%|clip**

Comment: @SharanaiyyaSwami Simply save the results to a text document then use another for loop or < echo/set statement to call the file into clipboard.

Comment: Is their any other way to copy that into clipboard

Comment: @SharanaiyyaSwami You can combine each address string ex: `E7E6E4E2E8E9 E7E6E4E2E8E9 E7E6E4E2E8E9` using the set command within the loop then `echo address | clip`.. Is that something that you are looking for?

Comment: if you want them line by line, just add a `(` before the very first `for` and a line `)|clip` just before `pause`. (piping the whole output to `clip`)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the method as coded below.

I've no idea how accurate it is, *(it is untested)*, but I'm certain that it is less likely to identify Bluetooth, MiniPort or WiFi adapters than any other 'batch' based method I've seen posted anywhere.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "MACs="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('
    "WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\WMI Path MSNdis_PhysicalMediumType Where (NdisPhysicalMediumType='0' Or NdisPhysicalMediumType='14') Get InstanceName 2>Nul"
') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
If Defined MACs Echo %MACs::=%|Clip
Exit /B

:Sub
For /F "Skip=1" %%C In ('
    "WMIC Path Win32_NetworkAdapter Where (AdapterTypeID='0' And Name='%*' And NetConnectionStatus='2' And PhysicalAdapter='True') Get MACAddress 2>Nul"
') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%D In ("%%C") Do If Not Defined MACs (
    Set "MACs=%%D") Else Call Set "MACs=%%MACs%% %%D"
```

I have filtered on a `NetConnectionStatus` of `2` as in your question. If having more than one Ethernet Adapter connected at the same time is unlikely, you should remove `And NetConnectionStatus='2'` from line `11`.

*Note: Network adapter names containing poison characters, may cause this code to fail.*